# Inline keyword not recognized in c module compiled inside a cpp project (VS2005)

Tags: c++, c, inline

I am developing an embedded C application in a C90-compliant compiler which, on the other hand, for testing and debugging purposes, is deployed in Matlab/Simulink interfacing the application with a CPP file. This bundle is compiled instead with Matlab MEX, which is configured to use Visual Studio 2005 to build.

This means we have one CPP file, and a couple of .C/.H files that are built altogether. This workflow has been successful for me, using the `#ifdef __cplusplus extern "C" {...}` trick on each C call.

However, I have come with a problem when the need of inline functions arose due to time constraints in the embedded application.

Next, SSCCE built in VS2005:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "c_method.h"

void main()
{
    for(int b = 0; b < 9; b++)
    int a = c_method(b);
}
```

**c_method.c**

```
#include "c_method.h"

inline int inline_fun(int x)
{
    return x+1;
}

int c_method(int b)
{
    return inline_fun(b);
}
```

**c_method.h**

```
#ifndef __C_METHOD_H__
#define __C_METHOD_H__

int c_method(int b);

#endif
```

Which provides the following errors:

```
c_method.c(7) : error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'inline'
c_method.c(8) : error C2085: 'inline_fun' : not in formal parameter list
c_method.c(8) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
```

I noticed I missed `extern "C" {...}` but did not work either.

As read here in SO, changing `c_method.c` to `c_method.cpp` will do the trick, **however** I'd rather have an alternative solution, if exists any, as I'm not very confident about the embedded C compiler accepting the cpp extension without coming whining to me...

Thank you.

**Added**

@πάντα ῥεῖ got with the answer. Creating an empty declaration of inline will do the trick.

However, as @Lundin suggests, I'll meditate the possibility of using another C compiler for the PC platform build.

Comment: I doubt `inline` is C90-compliant.

Comment: Visual studio 2005 doesn't support C99 (let alone C11), but rather implements the dated C90, which doesn't know inline functions

Comment: So, then, there is no compilation flag in VS2005 that would extend its C90 with inlining, as my embedded compiler provides by default?

Comment: If you insist to test compilation of the c code using VS2005, provide a (empty) define for `inline` via preprocessor option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visual studio doesn't support the `inline` keyword in C, because it does not implement C99 (which introduced that keyword).

However, it does support the Microsoft-specific keyword [`__inline`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8y1yy88%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in both C and C++. To make your code portable, you can do this:

```
#include "c_method.h"

#ifdef _MSC_VER
  #define inline __inline
#endif

inline int inline_fun(int x)
{
    return x+1;
}

int c_method(int b)
{
    return inline_fun(b);
}
```

Of course, in practice, you'd put the `inline` definition into a shared header file.

Comment: You'd probably want to check both `#if defined(_MSC_VER) && !defined(__cplusplus)`

Comment: @MSalters Fair enough, although I am assuming the OP to know which language they're using.

Comment: Inline functions are typically defined in headers, which may be included from both C and C++ files. (The question specifically mentions C and C++ being mixed). So, your assumption appears optimistic.

Answer (score 1):

There is no inline keyword in C90, so that would be why it doesn't work. It seems rather unlikely that a C compiler will compile C++. Visual Studio only does it because it is a C++ compiler, not a C compiler.

You have to check the embedded compiler for compiler extensions to the language. There is usually a compiler option you can enable.

Comment: So maybe instead, ask the question "how do I enable inlining on compiler x?".

Comment: Sure, the embedded compiler has an extension to C90 which provides inlining.

Comment: @Manex Visual Studio is simply put, a very bad compiler for writing portable, standard C code. I would check if there's an option to use a better PC compiler for writing the tests.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think in Visual Studio, inline function can be defined in a .c or .cpp file. You may try to move the definition of the inline function into the header file.